# rpmbuild complains about a missing directory

Tags: rpmbuild

I have a .spec file that is used to package two different versions of the a software. In the newer version of this software, there is a new directory (etc/scripts) that rpmbuild complains about not being included. I have included that with

```
%defattr(-,%karaf_user,%karaf_group,-)
%_karaf_path/etc/scripts
```

and this makes it work. Now when building the older version of this software, rpmbuild complains that the directory doesn't exist. Is there a way to make this directory optional, so rpmbuild includes it if it's there and ignores if not?

So far I've tried with `%config(missingok)` but that didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a conditional block like:

```
%defattr(-,%karaf_user,%karaf_group,-)
%if %{version} >= <1st-version-where-the-file-exists>
%_karaf_path/etc/scripts
%endif
```

Comment: Brilliant. I ended up creating the directory earlier on in the spec, so it would be there later. But yours is much nicer